# Traversing through pixels

Tags: image, matlab, set, pixel, belongs-to

Say that we have the following part of an algorithm, provided that I want to implement it in `matlab`:

```
k = 0;
while k<n 
among all pixels that "belong to" a set, select that pixel
k = k+1;
```

How can I implement?

- Determining if a pixel "belongs to" an image or a set of the image

Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand on "belongs to" ??

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in Matlab, image (gray/color) is represented as 2D/3D Matrix

For example,

```
I = imread("lena.jpg");
```

So, the size of the I is `m x n` for gray and `m x n x 3` for color

Now if you want to select a pixel that "belongs to" a subset of image (rectangle) `(xi yi) (w h)`.
The origin i.e., (1,1) pixel of the image is the top left corner.

```
Isub = I(xi:xi+w-1, yi:yf+h-1);
```

Also, you can just access pixels using `pixel = I(i,j);` `ith` pixel from top and `jth` pixel from left

If "belongs to" is something complex like all pixels which are red or something else, the approach/complexity would vary